# What is the yagna that allows any dwija to do another varna karma

Tags: scripture, dharma, parashurama, kshatriya

In the movie [Bajirao Mastani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajirao_Mastani), Baajirao Ballad Maratha Peshwa (Bramhin by birth) performs a Yagna after every battle he fights, in order to clear the sin of fighting war as it's a sin to fight if you are not a kshatriya.

So this means that any bramhin can fight in war by performing specific yagna, and even a Bramhin or Vaishya can do kshatriya karma in special circumstances? What did Lord Parshurama do in order to fight like that of kshatriya? Similarly any kshatriya can do bramhin karma or vaishya karma if yes then is the method same?

**What is that yagna which allows one to do different varna karma? What are other methods to perform another varna karma, like kshatriya doing bramhana/vaishya karma visa versa?**

Comment: "Since it is a sin to fight , if you are not a kshatriya."---According to which scriptural reference?

Answer (score 0):

Brahmanas qualities are Pathana, paathana, yajana acccording to the 18th chapter of the GITA. It is advised that brahmana should never become a shudra. He can maximum become a vaishya.

But right now in Kaliyuga almost all brahmanas have become shudras since they have accepted to get maintained by someone else, instead of living directly in shelter of Krishna, thinking him to be the maintainer of everything.

Thanks